# Callbacks function in GenServer

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am a beginner in Elixir and I'm trying to understand how to work with GenServer. What is magic for me is:

```
defmodule Stack do
  use GenServer

  # Callbacks

  def handle_call(:pop, _from, [h|t]) do
    {:reply, h, t}
  end

  def handle_cast({:push, item}, state) do
    {:noreply, [item|state]}
  end
end
```

The code is taken from GenServer docs. Why does the `call` function only return one value when then callback function returns `{:reply, h, t}`?

```
#Start the server
{:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(Stack, [:hello])

# This is the client
GenServer.call(pid, :pop)
#=> :hello #<<<<Why?
```

Is `{:reply, h, t}` not the returned value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `{:reply, h, t}` not a returned value?

`{:reply, h, t}` is the return value of `handle_call`, but you're not calling that function. You're calling `GenServer.call`, which internally calls `handle_call`, passing it the message, caller, and the current state, and if `handle_call` returns a 3 tuple of `{:reply, a, b}`, it sends back the second parameter, in this case `a` to the caller, and changes its state to `b`.